# Initial partition layout on the brand new laptop Dell Inspiron n1510

Tags: installation, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a brand new laptop and want to instal Windows 7 + Ubuntu 12.04. When I started to install Windows, I have discovered 2 partitions on my HDD as you can see on the picture below:

[image: Partition Listing]

- /dev/sda1 fat16 Label:DellUtility Size 39.19 MiB Used 235 KiB Flags:diag
- /dev/sda2 fat32 Label:OS          Size 1.95 Gib  Used 3.92 Mib Flags:boot

**What are they meant for and could I safely remove them ?**
What would i lose if i'll delete them save for opportunity to accept Dell End-user License agreement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell laptop tend to come with a recovery partition - you can press a key on startup and it give the option to restore the machine back to it's original software state. I would say that the first partition is where the recovery enviroment is installed, and the second is where the actual image is - smaller than I would have expected, but there you go.

You could delete the partitions outright to have a completely blank hard disk, then install Windows 7 and then Ubuntu (which is what I would do). I doubt that you would break any EULA - and you would not be able to restore it back to the factory settings afterwards in case you wanted to sell it on - if so, consider taking a whole disk image using CloneZilla or similar.